# Blazor avoid Authorizing on Index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I use `<AuthorizeView>`, `<NotAuthorized>` and `<Authorized>` in my MainLayout.razor.

App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

When i running my Blazor App there is a "Loading ..." and after this there is a "Authorizing ..." on the place where is @Body in my MainLayout.razor.
I want to avoid the "Authorizing ..." for Index Page because it is not looking nice when there is one second "Authorizing ..." when user visit first time the app. I also not want a empty text because all content from MainLayout.razor is rendered but not the @Body is which not looking nice.

I want that my @Body renders before "Authorizing ...".
Example project with counter (**there is no need of Authorizing for this page**)
Enter the page and missing body for one second:
[image: Enter the page and missing body for one second]

I wish something like this. Body rendered and "Authorizing ..." in background
[image: I wish something like this. Body rendered and "Authorizing ..." in background]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adapting the app.razor boilerplate code.

You can remove the next part of the code

```
          @* <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p role="alert">You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        *@
```

And replace it with the next code

```
<RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
             </RouteView>
```

Note however that by doing this you'll need to foresee the necessary validations for logins in the lower level pages

(still checking some things out but it seems to work)